# Custom feature image upload from front end only uploads folder name

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, file-upload

thanks for taking a look at my question.

**The Problem**

I need to be able to an upload feature image(thumbnail) that is associated with a post, the website that is being worked on has the ability to make posts from the front-end of the website.

**Custom code implemented**

in the post submission form I'm using a input element of type file:

```
<form class="compose-post-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  ...

 <input type="file" name="featured" id="featured">

 ...


</form>
```

The data is being sent to the backend on form submit with jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: t_ajax_url.ajax_url,
  data: $this.serialize() + "&tri_post_content="+article_content+"&article="+article,
  beforeSend: function () {
    is_sending = true;
  },
  success: function (data) {
    //window.location.replace(get_homepage_url+'trisine');

    var fd = new FormData();
    var file = $('#featured').val();
    fd.append("featured", file);
    fd.append('action', 'thumbnail_up');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: t_ajax_url.ajax_url,
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(status);
  }
});
```

This is the code that saves the thumbnail, for now I'm just testing with a post ID of 22:

```
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_thumbnail_up', 't_thumbnail_up' );
  function t_thumbnail_up(){

    $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = $_FILE['featured'];

    $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file['name'] );
    move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'] , $uploadfile );
    $filename = basename( $uploadfile );

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

    $attachment = array(
      'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
      'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
      'post_content' => '',
      'post_status' => 'inherit',
      'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
      );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

    update_post_meta(22, '_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    set_post_thumbnail( 22, $thumbnail_id );

    exit();
  }
```

The results are that something get's uploaded but it seems to only be the folders name, which is November's month number, the folder isn't actually created on the server:

[image: item available in Media Library menu]

Any help on how I can get this to work will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this functions to handle files from ajax.

```
<?php
$thumbnail = $_FILES[ 'featured' ];
$thumbnail_id = media_handle_sideload( $thumbnail, $post_id );
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $screenshot_id );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, doesn't seem to work but I appreciate the answer :)

Comment: @david-mendienta Can you please let me know what does var file = $('#featured').val(); and  $file = $_FILE['featured']; returns ?

Comment: returning array(0) {
}

Comment: @david-mendienta both returning empty? it means you are not getting the uploaded image correctly. You can inspect the file field after uploading the image and see where the image name is stored. You can probably get it with javascript and pass it to your ajax. Please let me know if you need further help :))